# Continuous Updating in Java Panel or Dialog Box

Tags: java, swing, redirect, dialog, console

I am a huge newbie and I have a program that normally prints items to the Java console window. I would like this program to become a window in which the user can interact with. The reason why I have not resorted to dialog boxes and panels is because this program require multiple prints to the console window. A traditional dialog box does not continuously update or compound on data that has already been printed on the box. I realize that there is another way of doing this by creating a program that mimics the Java console window. Because I am a noob, all of the java console redirecting questions and answers on this site have blown over my head. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html

Comment: *"Can anyone please help me?"*  What is your (specific) question?

Answer (score 2):

See maybe [How to Use Editor Panes and Text Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) will be helpful and give you some ideas.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is, every time you want to update the contents of a text box, call the setText function again. There's no "append" function on the contents: you have to give the entire contents each time. If you want something that mimics a console window, where messages continue to scroll, the simplest thing to do is to keep the entire contents in a StringBuilder. Each time you get new text append to the StringBuilder, then setText(myStringBuilder.toString).

You could, I supppose, write mybox.setText(mybox.getText()+"new contents"). That would be a little inefficient but probably not a big deal.

I don't know exactly what you're up to, but trying to redirect console output to a text box sounds like more nuisance that it's worth. Just put your data in the text box: don't write it somewhere else, then try to get it back and put it where you want it. I suppose if you have thousands of lines of code writing to the console and now you want it to go a text box, there might be value in not having to change all that code. But the structure of a console app is so different from the structure of a GUI app that changing the output statements would probably be the least of the things you'd have to rework.